# scrollBy doesn't work in Firefox and Opera

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, scroll, opera

This scrollBy function works in Internet Explorer, but ignores by Firefox and Opera. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

```
function scrollLeft(s){
document.frames['my_iframe'].scrollBy(-s,0);
window.frames['my_iframe'].scrollBy(-s,0);
}

function scrollRight(s){
document.frames['my_iframe'].scrollBy(s,0);
window.frames['my_iframe'].scrollBy(s,0);
}
```

Here is an example that works in Internet Explorer browser, but doesn't work in Firefox and Opera: http://igproject.ru/iframe-scrolling/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, etc. you need to use `scrollTo()` instead of `scrollBy()`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4CkML/

Example:

```
window.scrollTo(50,50);
```

You cannot use scrollTo/By if the domains don't match.  You can see here that a javascript error is produced:

http://jsfiddle.net/3CbZc/

Permission denied to access property 'scrollTo'

**Edit** - Updating answer to incorporate answer from long comment chain:

```
var oIF = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow; oIF.scrollBy(s, 0);
```

Comment: but I need to control the scroll function in the page where the iframe is set. scrollTo doesn't support addressing the element which I want to scroll. ((

Comment: I do this: `document.frames['my_iframe'].scrollTo(s,0); window.frames['my_iframe'].scrollTo(s,0);` but still not working...

Comment: If your iframe is in a different domain, you cannot scroll it.  But that's inconsistent with working in IE.  Could you post the HTML/url?  I cannot get this working in IE either.

Comment: I see that above, what about the html for the iframe?  How are those functions getting called?

Comment: Here is an example that works in Internet Explorer browser, but doesn't work in Firefox and Opera: http://igproject.ru/iframe-scrolling/index.htm

Comment: found the desicion for IE and Firefox: `var oIF = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow;
oIF.scrollBy(s, 0); ` how to make this script work in Opera?

Comment: That example scrolls fine in my Opera instances (tested both 11.10 and 11.50)